# Swiftc error when compiling nested/chained generic types

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I'm trying to implement an MVP pattern in Swift 3.

```
protocol View: class {

    // ...

}

class Presenter<ViewType: View> {

    // ...

}

class ViewController<ViewType: View, PresenterType: Presenter<ViewType>>: UIViewController, View {

    // ...

}
```

But I compile this code, I get this error in Xcode 8.0 (8A218a):

[image: Swiftc failed with exit code 1]

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Any workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of making everything use generics can you use dependency injection to provide your objects?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need generics for this.